# SUM of VARCHAR values in Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix

So am just trying to get the total number of reviews for each business however the REVIEWCOUNT column is of VARCHAR type so I tried this:

**SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(REVIEWCOUNT)) FROM BUSINESS**

but I get an *ERROR 201(22000): Illegal data*.

and then I tried this:

**SELECT SUM(CAST(REVIEWCOUNT AS INTEGER)) FROM BUSINESS**

but I get an *ERROR 203(22005): Type mismatch. VARCHAR and INTEGER for REVIEWCOUNT*

Comment: The column may be containing values that are not possible to cast to a number like an alphabet letter. Can you show a snippet of the data?

Comment: The data are just integer numbers from a csv file but i store them as varchar

Answer (score 0):

You can use TO_NUMBER function.

```
SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(REVIEWCOUNT)) FROM BUSINESS;
```

The reference is here
http://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#to_number